# How do I turn my simple script into a non polling version

Tags: signals, ipc

I wrote a simple bash script that reads out meta information about currently playing songs via playerctl. Right now the script is just unnecessary polling the information. I would like the script to only be invoked when the song changes. The actual player I am using is mostly spotify.

Is there any way I can use signals to make this happen? Maybe intercept signals spotify is sending?

I am not (only) interested in the solution to my problem. I would really like to learn more about the topic in general. How do I find out what signals are sent by processes, how can I intercept and use them etc? If that is even a possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[playerctl's github page](https://github.com/acrisci/playerctl) has an example for polling events with python.

The [API](https://dubstepdish.com/playerctl/api-index-full.html) might give you additional infos.

Answer (score 1):

Playerctl now has a follow switch that will print out just the changes. You can pass a format string as well to format the metadata how you want.

> playerctl metadata --format '{{ artist }} - {{ title }} {{ duration(position) }}|{{ duration(mpris:length) }}' --follow